# correct syntax to compare field with awk

Tags: command-line, scripts

First I aplogize for this idiot question .

I want to print a field if he is equals to a value .

The problem is that I'm using a non default field sperator and I didn't understand how to make it work .

```
 awk '{FS = "/" ; if($3=="value" print $3 }'
```

Thanks.

Comment: To assign an awk "special" variable like `FS`, either use a command line option like @Thor demonstrated, or use the `BEGIN` block. The way you've shown in the question means you reassign it for every line of the file. Also, you're missing the close-parentheses for your `if` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more awkish way is like this:

```
awk -F/ '$3 == "value" { print $3 }'
```

#### Explanation

- `-F` specifies the field separator
- Each block is executed based on the preceding condition, if non is given it is always true, the condition here is `$3 == "value"`.
- Regular expressions can be used instead if `==` is replaced with `~`.